# App crashes when passing extras between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

With these two java activities in Android Studio, I was wondering how to create objects/instances of another class (activity) AFTER converting the EditText variable type to an int upon getting input... Because whenever I run the code into my emulator and then press the onClick button to get to the SecondActivity screen, my app crashes:

**UPDATED AS OF 1/31/2016, 5:55PM:**

1. MainActivity.java:

   package sample.sampleapp;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   public EditText etHeight, etWidth;
   public int height, width;

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

        etHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterHeight);
        String ht = etHeight.getText().toString();
        height = Integer.parseInt(ht);
        i.putExtra("height", height);

        etWidth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterWidth);
        String wh = etWidth.getText().toString();
        width = Integer.parseInt(wh);
        i.putExtra("width", width);

        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
   ```

   }
2. SecondActivity.java:

   package sample.sampleapp;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private TextView tvResult, tvResult2;
   public int height, width;

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        height = i.getIntExtra("height", height);
        width = i.getIntExtra("width", width);

        tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        tvResult.setText(height);
        tvResult2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewResult2);
        tvResult2.setText(width);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
   ```

   }

Much appreciated!

Comment: Which is the exact row which throws the exception, what is the error message and what is the stack trace_

Comment: "my app crashes" - Then update your question with the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Don't have those static variables in your first activity. Instead pass any parameters you need to between your activities by adding them into the intent as extras.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("height", height);
intent.putExtra("width", width);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in SecondActivity retrieve those values from the intent in onCreate:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int height = intent.getIntExtra("height");
int width = intent.getIntExtra("width");
```